Does the Seed Money voucher do anything if you're using the green deck?
I'm playing a Balatro run with the Green Deck, which states

At end of each Round:
$2 per remaining Hand.
$1 per remaining Discard.
Earn no Interest

The shop is offering a Seed Money voucher which says:

Raise the cap on interest earned in each round to $10

Does the Seed Money Voucher do anything if you're using the Green Deck?

Seed money (and it's upgraded counterpart Money Tree) does not generate interest when playing green deck [1][2]. However, taking the voucher can still be beneficial to ensure it doesn't appear in later shops (useful if you're going endless).
[1] I know this because of the multiple times I have bought seed money while gold staking green deck, only to realise my mistake.
[2] https://balatrogame.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Deck
